# Cannot iterate zipped list in csv writerow()

Tags: python, django, csv

I tried to generate csv file from zipped list consists of **1 Object** and **3 int lists**

```
items = zip(object, list1, list2, list3)
```

I looped the zipped list as follows but when I tried download the csv, there are no data:

```
for object, list1, list2, list3 in items:
    writer.writerow([object.name, object.department, object.section, list1, list2, list3])
```

I checked if the data cannot be read or missing by using the segment code below, however it can properly print all the data:

```
 for object, list1, list2, list3 in items:
    print(str(object.name) + ": " + str(list1) + "/" + str(list2) + "/" + str(list3))
```

I'm not sure where's the part that went wrong here as it doesn't print any error message.

Comment: Hard to say from what is given, but some naive guesses: 
1. the zip iterator is already consumed at the point where `writerow` loop occurs, or
2. writer is not opened correctly (open a file somewhere else?)

Comment: `zip()` takes _iterables_ as arguments: Is object an [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable)? (Don't use `object` as a variable name, use `obj` etc. instead - `object` is a builtin function.)

Comment: The problem is solved. It seems the zip iterator is already consumed before the `writerow` loop occurs. I'm curious, does it means zip iterator can only consumed once? @cjackal

Comment: That is pretty much [standard behaviour](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator)